# delete file issue for Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, macbook

I am using a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.5. I am new to this development environment, and previously worked on Windows.

I have tried when select a file (e.g. a ppt file on desktop), then I press Delete key on keyboard. The file is not deleted (seems no effect). How to delete a file from keyboard?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command + Delete